# Can simplecart be integrated with jotform?

Tags: javascript, simplecart, jotform

I am using Github pages for my website, and it does not allow PHP.

But since I am doing an e-commerce website, I need a shopping cart - with buttons "**add item to cart**" and "**checkout**".

The idea is, upon checkout, the user will have to fill out the name, address, email, and contact number. And his/her orders in the shopping cart will be the default message body.

Can I integrate simplecart.js to Jotform? (the orders will be sent as parameter for message body in Jotform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[simplecart-js](http://simplecartjs.org) are my favorite cart script, been using that on every website i made that need an checkout function.

it has good [documentation](http://simplecartjs.org/documentation)
for your need, to get the simplecart item, you can use [`simplecart.each`](http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/simplecart-each) function.

maybe like this:

```
var cart = '', total = 0;
simpleCart.each(function(item, i){
   var subtotal = item.get('price') * item.get('quantity');
   cart += i + '. ' + item.get('fullname') + ' >> $' + item.get('price') + ' x ' + item.get('quantity') + ' = $' + subtotal + '\n';
   total += subtotal;
});
cart += '\n\nTotal = $' + total;
$('#messagebody').val(cart);
```

the output on content body will be something like this:

```
1. product 1 >> $100 x 2 = $200
2. product 2 >> $75 x 3 = $225

Total = $425
```